# Unit testing http json response in Golang

Tags: json, go

I am using `gin` as my http server and sending back an empty array in json as my response:

```
c.JSON(http.StatusOK, []string{})
```

The resulting json string I get is `"[]\n"`.  The newline is added by the json Encoder object, see [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/JN5eV6UqVzE).

Using `goconvey`, I could test my json like

```
So(response.Body.String(), ShouldEqual, "[]\n")
```

But is there a better way to generate the expected json string than just adding a newline to all of them?

Comment: Comparing against the raw output produced by a marshal is problematic since anytime you use a map the order is not guaranteed. In my tests I always unmarshal then compare.

Comment: @jmaloney, Can you please give me a code sample?

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/vA-n_f9VoI

Answer (score 5):

You should first unmarshal the body of the response into a struct and compare against the resulting object. Example:

```
result := []string{}
if err := json.NewDecoder(response.Body).Decode(&result); err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}
So(len(result), ShouldEqual, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Unmarshal the body into a struct and the use Gocheck's DeepEquals
https://godoc.org/launchpad.net/gocheck

Answer (score 2):

You may find [jsonassert](https://github.com/kinbiko/jsonassert) useful.
It has no dependencies outside the standard library and allows you to verify that JSON strings are semantically equivalent to a JSON string you expect.

In your case:

```golang
// white space is ignored, no need for \n
jsonassert.New(t).Assertf(response.Body().String(), "[]")
```

It can handle any form of JSON, and has very friendly assertion error messages.

Disclaimer: I wrote this package.

Answer (score 0):

I made it this way. Because I don't want to include an extra library.

```
tc := testCase{
    w: httptest.NewRecorder(),
    wantResponse: mustJson(t, map[string]string{"message": "unauthorized"}),
}
...

if tc.wantResponse != tc.w.Body.String() {
    t.Errorf("want %s, got %s", tt.wantResponse, tt.w.Body.String())
}

...
func mustJson(t *testing.T, v interface{}) string {
    t.Helper()
    out, err := json.Marshal(v)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    return string(out)
}
```